# Strange behavior when submitting post request in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cors, angular2-http

I realize my title is a bit vague, but here is my situation.  I have just started an application in which I am implementing JWT for authentication.  I have my server side set up, and can verify it is working as intended.

The strangeness is that when you click the button to log in, in Chrome and Firefox it sends the request once, without the body of the request.  In Edge it submits it twice, once the way Chrome does, then a second time pretty much immediately afterwards with the body intact.

I have the login hard coded right now directly into the post request to try and eliminate as many things as possible.

header.component.html

```
<ul id="links">
    <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/census">Census</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services/Authentication.Service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _auth: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this._auth.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(result => {

            });
    }

}
```

Authentication.Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
 
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;
 
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        // set token if saved in local storage
        var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
    }
 
    login(usn: string, psw: string): Observable<boolean> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/auth', JSON.stringify({ username: "email-removed", password: "password-removed" }), options)
                    .map((response: Response) => { return true; });
    }
}
```

Here is the request for the first request I see from Chrome, the response is empty

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/auth
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8888
Response Headers
view source
Allow:POST, OPTIONS
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 31 Dec 2016 00:08:05 GMT
Server:Werkzeug/0.11.13 Python/3.5.2
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Host:localhost:5000
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

This is the second request as captured by fiddler. It never happens when I click the button in chrome

```
POST http://localhost:5000/auth HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
content-type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.7,zh-Hans;q=0.5,es-US;q=0.3,es;q=0.2
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
Content-Length: 58
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

{"username":"removed","password":"removed"}
```

And the response for the second

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE0ODMxNDE5NDIsImlkZW50aXR5IjoiNTg2NmJiNDkwYzE3ZDdlMzk4MTk5MWNhIiwiZXhwIjoxNDgzMTQyMjQyLCJuYmYiOjE0ODMxNDE5NDJ9.VZGBYnPKPwyR0lWdG3kR8AecbLNlYCHMC1nimAHeP3w"
}
```

Here's another oddity/clue for you. The backend is a Python/Flask rest.  As I watch the requests come in this is what I see.  The ones that say OPTIONS are the empty requests, the ones that say POST are second ones that only happen in Edge and are correct.
[image]

Comment: What do you get in the response? Is the page hosted in the same exact host (`http://localhost:5000`)? Or a different one? (if the port is different then the host is)

Comment: The one that has no body returns an empty 200 response, the one with the login and password included returns my JWT.

Comment: Can you share the request and response as viewed in the chrome developer tools network tab?

Comment: The Chrome only shows the first request with no body.  I'll update the question with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're having problems with a cross origin request.
The page host (`localhost:4200`) is different than the destination (`localhost:5000`).

When that happens chrome issues a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests):

> Unlike simple requests (discussed above), "preflighted" requests first
>   send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on the
>   other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is safe
>   to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they may
>   have implications to user data.

The response you get from there server doesn't include the needed [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers), and therefor chrome doesn't issue the actual `POST` request.

Comment: I believe you're right. Always the simple things that get me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that there is a trailing slash at the end of the route you are calling. So instead of calling

```
'http://localhost:5000/auth'
```

you target

```
'http://localhost:5000/auth/'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned Chrome issues preflighted request.
To bypass that you could install [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) to enable CORS and add  *'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *'* to your headers. That worked for me with django on localhost:8000 and angular2 on localhost:4200.